# Are certain comments only appropriate for moderators to say, or should I expect any user to say them?

Tags: discussion, comments, moderation

I have come across random questions where high-rep users added comments like

> “Welcome to SO...”
>
> “X is not how you should be using this site”
>
> “Please delete your answer...”

I assumed these users were moderators because of how the comments were written. When I visited these users’ profiles, there were no indications they were moderators. My conclusion was that they were pretending to be so, and such a behavior is usually frowned upon in online communities and games. Are users allowed to do that on Stack Overflow?

Comment: A moderator can just delete the answer. No need to ask. None of those comments strike me as impersonating a moderator. Especially the "welcome" one.

Comment: Technically, all users on the site _are_ moderators to some degree. High-rep users posting comments about how to use the site are trying to help guide you (or whoever they're commenting to) better understand and use the site. You don't have to be a mod to do that! (The kind of moderator that you're thinking of is, on the network here, denoted with a diamond next to their usernames. These are "diamond mods" and are the "all powerful" users on the sites. There are only a handful of them, so with how many questions/new users we get a day, they can't pay special attention to each.)

Comment: @Kendra But don’t you have to be *elected* as a moderator?

Comment: I am not an official moderator, so I am always polite, eg  'Please take your dubious buffer overflows code injections and other malware develoment stuff, leave the site and never come back'.

Comment: A user doesn't have to be a moderator in order to moderate. A moderator's *obligation* is to moderate; a normal user has fewer tools to moderate available and isn't obligated to moderate -- but a normal user *can* moderate.

Comment: Reputation points are used as an indicator for how much the community trusts a user. The more reputation you get, the more the community trusts you and the more moderation privileges you get. Stack Overflow is a community moderated site, which means that all of us are moderators. We just might not all be diamond (♦) which *are* elected by the community and have more moderation powers than any regular users.

Comment: So are you guys saying there is a “social pyriamid” of moderators—diamond on top and normal users on the bottom?

Comment: You have to be elected to be a _diamond_ moderator. Due to how the reputation and [privilege](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges) system works here, users slowly (Or quickly in some cases) gain access to new moderation tools, such as review queues and the ability to vote to delete, making 25k+ users almost as good as moderators.

Comment: [we amortize the overall moderation cost of the system across thousands of teeny-tiny slices of effort contributed by regular, everyday users](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/05/a-theory-of-moderation/)

Comment: [You'll be able to work alongside our community moderators to keep the site focused and helpful](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) -- Stack Overflow tour.

Comment: *"So are you guys saying there is a “social pyramid” of moderators—diamond on top and normal users on the bottom?"* Exactly. The more rep you have, the more moderation tools are available to you. Unless you're a diamond mod, then almost all of the moderation tools are available to you regardless of rep.

Comment: Thanks for the info guys, but any reason for the downvotes? Not sure what makes this question a bad one...

Comment: @Kendra Or *almost elected and then appointed* in the case of moderators called up to action in special circumstances.

Comment: I can only guess (until someone says otherwise) that the downvotes stem from a lot of users thinking maybe you just didn't look into this hard enough. I personally think this is a decent question, and something users used to traditional forums could get tripped up by, but others might think this was an obvious question that you could have found on your own. (We won't know until someone says why they voted, however, and no one is ever required to give their reason for a downvote.)

Comment: @JonKantner on meta down votes are different. In this case they might mean: Yes, users are allowed to do that. Votes here don't affect reputation. Read more in [What is meta](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/help/whats-meta)

Comment: @TylerH Oh, I completely forgot about that. Thanks for reminding me. (I'll probably add that to my answer, if you don't mind.)

Comment: @Kendra Sure, it's not like I own that information :-)

Comment: @Kendra I have Googled my situation before, but I could not find an answer, so that is what made me ask this question. I’m not too familiar with this unique moderation system, as I am used to forums and online games adopting a report function to control bad behavior.

Comment: @JonKantner Don't worry about the downvotes, they're handed out like candy here on meta. Your confusion is understandable and this is a fine question.

Comment: @JonKantner Downvotes on Meta don't change your reputation; don't worry. They also are used to mean "I agree with this/think it's a good idea" or "I disagree with this/think it's a bad idea", though in your question's case, it's really a good question worth asking, so I'm not sure why it's received so many downvotes. I've rewritten your question title to be more clear, hopefully that will stem the tide.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

So what you've been seeing isn't a case of users impersonating moderators, but instead users attempting to guide other users on how to use the site appropriately.

On the Stack Exchange network, almost every user has some degree of moderation abilities. A user first gets these privileges at a mere 15 rep- The ability to upvote good content and use several of the system flags to bring bad content to attention of other users. From there, you gain more tools to use to help moderate and curate content the more reputation you get.<sup>1</sup>

Now, the moderators you're thinking of are the typical "all-powerful" users that help keep a community in line. We have those here as well, but these elected, and occasionally appointed,<sup>2</sup> officials are denoted with a diamond (♦) next to their usernames. Note that employees of Stack Overflow can also have the diamond,<sup>3</sup> and the [Community ♦](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/-1/community) user has one.<sup>4</sup>

There are only a handful of moderators per site, so the community at large is expected to help flag, delete, edit, and otherwise moderate content. If regular users did not have access to these features, we would need, likely, hundreds of mods just to run Stack Overflow and keep the quality up. It would also likely have been harder, if not impossible, to get to the point that we are today.

To answer your main question, *yes* it is wrong to impersonate a mod. However, as the ♦ character is not allowed in usernames, any user who has been around long enough to learn how to pick out an elected moderator will know the impostor is, well, being an impostor. However they are trying to use that pretend power can be flagged and brought to the attention of the diamond mods to handle.

---

<sub><sup>1</sup> To see some of the other abilities you can unlock, and when, check out the [Privileges page.](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges)

<sup>2</sup> Appointed moderators are usually a result of being *almost* elected, and then a position suddenly needing filled and a runner-up in the election being asked to step up. (Thanks to [TylerH](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/2756409/tylerh) for pointing this out in [a comment.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/308623/are-users-allowed-to-pretend-to-be-moderators?noredirect=1#comment262041_308623))

<sup>3</sup> Note that not all employees have diamonds on all sites- Rather, they only have diamonds on sites they need them for.

<sup>4</sup> The Community ♦ user is a sort of an automated user that owns abandoned bounties and votes (from account deletion or disassociation), among other things. You can check out the list in its "About Me" section on its profile.</sub>

Answer (score 16):

Well technically high rep users *are* moderators (of sorts). What they aren't is **diamond** moderators.  (However when users refer to someone as a "moderator", this is typically shorthand for a diamond moderator.)

Everyone has some degree of moderation ability - but for regular users it requires several users to work in concert (but not collusion) to effect change.

- Six spam flags will delete a post.
- Five close votes will put a question on hold or migrate it to another site.
- A single vote from someone with a gold badge in a tag can close a question as a duplicate of another.
- Three (or more for high scoring questions) delete votes will finally remove it from the site.
- etc.

Comments *can* be part of that moderation process but often just add noise so they should be used sparingly and with care.